# How to resolve non relative paths with testcafe when using typescript

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, tsconfig

I'm working on test automation using [testcafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe) and I have integrated typescript into the project. I have set up non-relative paths, see below, which work for the IDE but when compiled I'm sure they're not being reverted to their original paths.

I have tried setting the moduleResolution option to a node in tsconfig.json although this did not work.

Is there a way this can be achieved with testcafe's configuration, or another way?

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@page-model/*": [
            "page-model/*",
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
// test-file.ts
import { Home } from '@page-model/home'
```

The error I receive when running `testcafe chrome test-file.ts` is that it cannot find the module I am referencing. Obviously due to the fact it's not being transformed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue with the TypeScript module resolution and NodeJS, not with TestCafe.

I created a sample that demonstrates the issue without TestCafe. Please see the following code:

index.ts

```
function log(t:any) {
    console.log(t);
}

log(require('@page-model/model').HEADER);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "models",
    "paths": {
      "@page-model/*": [ "main/*" ]
    },
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

I compiled the `index.ts` file with the `tsc` util and got the following js code:

index.js

```
function log(t) {
    console.log(t);
}
log(require('@page-model/model').HEADER);
```

The path was not resolved by the TS compiler. I searched for possible solutions on the StackOverflow and they recommend trying the https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths module.